# Поля у CardView внутри ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Здравствуйте.

Имеется `CardView`, внутри которого находится `TextView`. Сам `CardView` обернут в `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="здесь большой текст"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Как видно из кода разметки, у `CardView` добавлены поля слева и справа -- и они действительно есть и отображаются корректно.

Требуется добавить к `CardView` поля сверху и снизу.

Добавление `android:layout_marginTop` к `CardView` ведет к добавлению поля сверху, но в таком случае `ScrollView` не прокручивает контент до конца.

Добавление `android:layout_marginBottom` к `CardView` вообще никаких изменений не вносит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно добавить эти поля.

PS. На самом деле разметка намного сложнее, это лишь минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Может попробовать `padding` и `clopToPadding="false"` у `ScrollView`?

Comment: @lllyct, В принципе, если к `CardView` добавить `layout_marginLeft` и `layout_marginRight`, а к `ScrollView` -- `android:clipToPadding="false"`, `paddingTop` и `paddingBottom`, то уже почти получается похожее на то, что нужно. Но в таком случае скроллбар начинается от конца верхнего отступа и заканчивается у начала нижнего, а хотелось бы чтобы он по высоте занимал и оба паддинга.

Comment: Вроде бы у ScrollView есть атрибуты про расположение скроллбаров, но проще сделать как советует Юрий и добавить дополнительный FrameLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен допольнительный контейнер.

Т.е. поместите в ScrollView что-то, например FrameLayout, которому задайте нужные паддинги, а уже в него поместите CardView. Или назначьте маржины уже для CardView.

Comment: Вроде и пробовал такой вариант, но почему-то не получалось, сейчас попробовал -- все ок. Мистика :) Спасибо!